# How to group a column which is in hours by days and months in a pivot table?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am new to excel pivot tables and need some help from excel experts here. I have a table with agent name, ticket number and hours since the ticket was assigned to the agent as can be seen below:

**SOURCE**

```
  agent             ticket               hours since assigned
-----------------------------------------------------------
  agent1            12345                     23
  agent2            23456                     10
  agent2            78964                     45
  agent5            45567                     148
  agent5            98654                     15
  agent6            54678                     2
  agent4            76543                     100
  agent4            98765                     56
```

**THE PIVOT TABLE** that I am looking for is - number of tickets agentwise grouped by days. I hope this is possible in excel. Please guide me.

```
agent        1 to 2 days          2 to 3 days            3 to 4 days
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
agent1           2                  5                        4
agent2           5
agent4                                                       2
```

Is it also possible to group the same data by weeks, months?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably pull this off with calculated fields in the pivot table, but it may get a little hairy. I think your best bet would be to calculate these in your sheet that feeds the pivottable with new columns.

A formula like the following (Assuming your hours column in `C`) and copy down:

For 1 to 2 days:

```
=IF(AND(C2/24>0,C2/24<=2), 1, 0)
```

For 2 to 3 days:

```
=IF(AND(C2/24 >2,C2/24<=3), 1, 0)
```

And so on..

Then just include those in the pivot table:

[image]

You could also remove the `if()` formula since the result is always a 0 or 1 (which is the same as `false` or `true`)

For 1 to 2 days:

```
=AND(C2/24>0,C2/24<=2)
```

For 2 to 3 days:

```
=AND(C2/24 >2,C2/24<=3)
```

[image]

If you really wanted to get bare bones, you could swap out that `AND()` formula with just multiplication between the two conditions:

For 1 to 2 days:

```
=(C2/24>0) * (C2/24<=2)
```

For 2 to 3 days:

```
=(C2/24>2) * (C2/24<=3)
```

Which will return a 0 or 1 again.